# Ambiguous use of 'gl_id'

Tags: swift4, xcode10

I am getting this error in below code.

In Xcode10. How to fix it

```
Reference to var 'gl_id' of 'Taskdetail' depends on '@objc' inference deprecated in Swift 4
```

if let Tasks = user?.tasks {
                for task in tasks {
                    print("To fetch task ((task as AnyObject).gl_id)")

```
                if let taskId = (task as AnyObject).gl_id {
                    if let id = taskId {
                        fetchtaskValues(id, limit: limit, delegate: delegate)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set Swift 3 @objc inference -> Default

- go to project Setting
- click Build Settings
- Search Swift 3 @objc Inference
- set Default

[image]

Comment: @Sabiir Ahmed. Thank you for reply I did this step. Still it shows same error.